# Unable to play wav data using FileInputStream and Clip

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to play .wav files using AudioInputStream and clip methods. My code is as follows:

```
fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
int result = fc.showOpenDialog(add);
try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                AudioInputStream as = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
                try {
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(as);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    clip.start();
                } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

}       `
```

When selecting a .wav file i get following error message:

> mark/reset not supported

Any Ideas how i can fix that? First time working with audio files.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the JavaFX MediaPlayer which is way easier to use and supports more codecs.

Comment: Is there no way to fix this one? Why do I get the UnsupportedAudioFile exception?

Comment: cause your .wav file is not supported by your current choice of library.

Comment: Either you convert your audio file into a supported codec/format or you use the JavaFX MediaPlayer which supports a lot of codecs